# Make Time Machine select another backup drive automatically

Tags: mac, time-machine

I have two external harddrives that I use with Time Machine, alternating between them.

When I do a backup on one of them, unplug it and then plug in the other one, Time Machine will not use it automatically. I need to open the preferences, click "Select disk" and choose the drive from a menu. Then I unplug it, try to use the first one, same story.

How can I configure Time Machine to just use either of them as soon as they are attached?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mountain Lion added this capability. You can simply add multiple backup disks and Time Machine will rotate between all of those that are attached at that time.

[image: Mountain Lion - Multiple Backup Volumes]

If Time Machine is unable to backup to one of them, it will notify you after 10 days, just as with a single disk.

If you are unable to upgrade to Mountain Lion, [Tedium](http://www.tediumapp.com/about-tedium/) allows you to switch between multiple Time Machine volumes via a menu bar applet. You could then automate the switching based on environmental cues, such as the WiFi SSIDs available, using [ControlPlane](http://www.controlplaneapp.com/feature-list/). There are also lots of scripts out there that provide the same functionality.

However, since all of these work-arounds are unsupported, upgrading to Mountain Lion would be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Not a Mac user, so cannot validate the answer.)</sup>

The article [Automatically switching between different Time Machine disks](http://blog.liip.ch/archive/2009/01/20/automatically-switching-between-different-time-machine-disks.html) describes an approach that could help solve this problem :

> With some googling I found out, that the destination disk was written
>   in the `/Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine BackupAlias`
>   property and could be read with
>
> ```
> defaults read /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine BackupAlias
> ```
>
> This gives you a rather long string starting with something like
>   <00000000 014e0002 .... That's what you need for later. And for both
>   disks.
>
> Next I wrote two little shell scripts, looking like this:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> defaults write /Library/Preferences/com.apple.TimeMachine BackupAlias '<00000000 014e0002 ....>'
> ```
>
> and started them, when needed. No more half a dozen mouse-clicks and
>   typing in that password every time, just calling that script was
>   enough, but still not perfect. [Jiayong Ou](http://twitter.com/jiayongou) to the rescue, which
>   made me aware of the context-and-location-aware and free application
>   [MarcoPolo](http://www.symonds.id.au/marcopolo/). A little bit of configuring and I have now a fully
>   automated backup solution at home and at the office. I additionally
>   added the line
>
> ```
> /System/Library/CoreServices/backupd.bundle/Contents/Resources/backupd-helper -auto &
> ```
>
> to my script and a delay of 30 seconds in MarcoPolo, so that my backup
>   started immediately when I'm online again and after the disk
>   preference actually switched. Doesn't work always, since it's aborting
>   a maybe running old backup, but seems not to do harm either.